# How to save files over socket into list

Tags: java, sockets

I have a method that works perfectly, but instead of having it write to a file, how do I have it add each line of the file to a list? (Some files are .docx and some are .txt)

```
private static void saveMultiple(Socket socket) {
    try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        int filesCount = dis.readInt();
        File[] files = new File[filesCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
            long fileLength = dis.readLong();
            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            files[i] = new File("/Users/.../Desktop/Data/" + fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            for (int x = 0; x < fileLength; x++) {
                bos.write(bis.read());
            }
            bos.close();
        }
        dis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "a line".  A binary file isn't likely to have any lines

Comment: If you don't want to write a file in the file system you can't have a list of them. But you can have a list of byte arrays I guess..

Answer (score 0):

This part of you code:

```
bos.write(bis.read());
```

Basically read 1 byte from the socket and writes it into file. Now instead of doing this, you can buffer the bytes into a byte array, and use java.util.String `String(byte[] bytes)` constructor to turn it into a String. Consider using `ByteInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method.

You have to take into account the character encoding and memory consumption too.